# Querying mongodb for a nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have `Book` objects in my mongoDb that look like this (very simplified):

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("620e341dbf575892d9396dc2"),
  "title": "my title",
  "author": {
    "_id": ObjectId("620e341dbf575892d9396dd4"),
    "surname": "My surname"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to query and get all books by an author, and so far I've tried:

```
const booksByAuthor = await Book.find({ author: { _id: "620e341dbf575892d9396dd4" } });
```

and

```
const booksByAuthor = await Book.find({ 'author._id': "620e341dbf575892d9396dd4" } );
```

But in no case I'm getting the existing books from the given author, and I'm only getting empty arrays.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your second attempt should work. I would guess the issue is somewhere in the details you have not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem for 1st query:

When you want to query in a nested field you have to use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) as you do in the second query.
The problem to not use dot notation is mongo match the entire object (even the fields order) so is not a good way... you can check simple examples like:

- [This one](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZdawwIwEYHH): The object is found because the object is exactly the same.
- [Another this one](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sdr8p7Fj5nu) where the object has the same fields and values from two objects in the collection but... querying using an object the order matters, so only returns one.

The problem for 2nd query:

I think the problem here is you are matching `string` vs `ObjectId`. The syntaxis is correct (dot notation) but when mondo match the values one of them is string and another is ObjectId.

So you can try this query:

```
const booksByAuthor = await Book.find({ 'author._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId("620e341dbf575892d9396dd4") } );
```

Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3qDb3RiGOdn) with your query, matching string and ObjectId none result is returned, but parsing string to ObjectId... [magic appears](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CR1cURrhnC3)

Comment: OP is using mongoose, which will cast the string to `ObjectId` automatically, so that's not the issue here.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! Thank you!

Comment: Despite using mongoose this returns the desired result. I mean the solution by J.F. solves the problem. I'm not sure if I was missing something before, though.